# Delete data-attribute with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to delete the  data attribute `data-snap-ignore="true"` for resolutions lower than 880px.

Just to prevent the drag option allowed or disabled depending on the devices.

HTML:

```
<div id="content" class="snap-content" data-snap-ignore="false">
 Content of the website
</div>
```

The function code for `data-snap-ignore`:

```
            var target = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement,
                ignoreParent = utils.parentUntil(target, 'data-snap-ignore');

            if (ignoreParent) {
                utils.dispatchEvent('ignore');
                return;
            }
```

Since the code does not have the values of `true` or `false`, I tried to make it work with the following demo.

DEMO TRYOUT: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ByPmC/)

Code used on the demo (does not work):

```
if($(window).width() < 300) {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore','false');
} else {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore','true');
}
```

Seems like should work but it does not (does not change from true to false).

Otherwise I am thinking on modifying

```
} else {
    $('#content').attr('data-snap-ignore','true');
}
```

for

```
} else {
    $('#content').attr('','');
}
```

since just wanted to delete the data-attribute.

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine for me, but if you really want to remove the attribute use [**removeAttr()**](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ByPmC/1/

Otherwise I can't see it working, since resizing the deskopt it keeps displaying the same attribute

Comment: Uhm, it doesn't change on resize, why would it? You'll need an event handler for that.

Comment: an event handler? Excuse me, because I am not used with javascripts so I can't figure out what do you mean

Comment: Things doesn't change if you resize the window or click a button, those are events, and you'll need event handlers to capture those events -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresizehttps://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onresize

Comment: Should this update work as the event mentioned before?

http://jsfiddle.net/ByPmC/4/ (Updated to 4th version)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ByPmC/5/